# LNK2001 unresolved external symbol class tensorflow::TensorShapeProtoDefaultTypeInternal

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I try to parse Tensorflow Graph, as compiling without error but I get error "unresolved external symbol class TensorShapeProtoDefaultTypeInternal" tensor_shape.pb.h. I try to include tensorflow.lib, and also add all obj files to Visual Studio project but can not pass.
I'm using Tensorflow 1.6.0 with Visual Studio 2015 update 3.

class TensorShapeProtoDefaultTypeInternal define in tensor_shape.pb.h

```

```
NodeDef* node_def
....
const AttrValue& value = node_def->attr().at( "value" );
const TensorProto& tensor_proto = value.tensor();

const DataType tensor_data_type = tensor_proto.dtype();
const TensorShapeProto &tensor_shape = tensor_proto.tensor_shape();
....
```

```

Does anyone have an idea what might cause these errors?

Comment: Check your includes and project settings are correct

Comment: anyway I found the way to fix it, by generating proto file and including in my project.